# Why is CodeBlocks 13.12 giving the following two errors during debug?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am new to CodeBlocks. I am using CodeBlocks 13.12, along with the included Mingw GCC compiler, and I am getting the following 2 errors:

[image: CodeBlocks Error Outputs]

Probably a little more useful: The build log -

[image: CodeBlocks Build Log]

The project is just a simple "Hello World" program right now, and I am just trying to get the libraries setup for use. There are no other errors shown,
and I have not enabled or disabled any compiler options.

I definitely have the main.cpp file in the listed search path.
What. The. Actual.

Also, what does the system mean by "Party"?

Comment: can you include a partial screenshot of the area where these things are appearing?

Comment: @Matt McNabb Posted it.

Comment: Wow...I didn't see the line about not finding the SDL. That's embarrassing.

Comment: It looks like mingw32 is not coping with your paths containing spaces -- as you can see from the build log and the items under "File" column of build messages, it thinks you've specified "Party" and "Projects\Normal_Map..." as filenames on the commandline

Answer (score 1):

Ok. The answer is I am an idiot who didn't check all the output windows.
I didn't properly link the SDL library.

Comment: ...or that. That could be it too. Ha ha, glad you solved it. I can't tell you how many times that sort of thing has happened to me. >.>

Comment: @JasonMc92 I am new to CodeBlocks so I'm not familiar with all the output window functions. Oh well. :p

Comment: I don't see how that would be related to the errors you showed ... are you successfully building now?

Comment: OK, I think that is unrelated to the spaces problem

Comment: Well...you are correct. Now I need to solve my build flag issues. If you make a formal answer, I'll give you the credit for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this "can't find .o" error on a semi-regular basis. It could be other things, but the first thing you need to try to do is to **delete the `obj` folder from your project directory** and then **completely rebuild the project.** The Rebuild button is on the toolbar (the two arrows in a circle), next to your Build and Run buttons.

If you're still getting errors, it would depend on your project's paths and how you set it up.

Comment: It is most likely due to me failing to properly link the SDL lib. I am using GNU GCC which requires more annoying setup.